# Reducer error cancelling all Tasks, killing all sagas

Tags: redux, redux-saga

Twice recently I've encountered an error in a reducer due to an undefined variable.

In both cases this resulted in the application becoming unresponsive because the error had a cascading effect and all my saga "take" commands were cancelled.
e.g.

```
Tasks cancelled due to error:
takeEvery(actionName1, sl)
takeLatest(actionName2, Yi)
```

etc.

Also, in both cases the fix was simple - to add defensive coding to the reducer to prevent this.

However, the effect is devastating on the app if the code allows an *undefined* to slip through and I'm wondering if there is another way?

- Should I wrap the switch in the reducer with a try/catch?
- Is there a
  way to stop all the tasks cancelling when an error occurs?

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer that works but I would still appreciate comments to validate if this is the best answer as I'm relatively new to Redux.

I implemented my first suggestion from above and it seems to work well and would stop my problem

```
try {
    switch (action.type) {
        case '...':
    ...
} catch (err) {
    // Do something with the error here
    return state;  // state is unchanged
}
```

Is this correct or is there a better way?
EDIT: This needs to be a pure component so "Do something with the error here" has to mean add something to state to track the error. Anything else needs to be done by something acting on that state change.

Comment: I think part of the answer here is to solve the situation that was causing your reducer to end up handling an undefined value in the first place.  It either needs to be coded more defensively, or the data should be validated before the action is dispatched.